# Background and Image color change

Tags: web, gif, animated-gif, visual-web-developer

Came across this webpage http://totallytransparent.tumblr.com/ Can anybody please tell me how this works? how does the background color and image color change/ match colors.

Comment: [JS version](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19657772/2202732) of that color transition. [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/j6RpD/2/) Also added the hat image. As mentioned in the answers it's a transparent png file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The background is an animated gif (http://static.tumblr.com/f13b0a6a22dd72346d930867ce349dff/zatppvx/DVQmt82k8/tumblr_static_colour-big.gif), the other images have transparent areas and the background "shines through".

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response. I'm a little confused. The logo Tt is a transparent  image but if you scroll down there's a Sweater image on the left side. It's got texture on it. If the image is transparent how does it retain its texture (and match background color) ?

Comment: [The sweater image](http://25.media.tumblr.com/8b5fb79e75f38267c938882f1c8279a0/tumblr_mx941kJfBm1s5jjtzo1_500.png) is gray if you open it by itself. The image is a little transparent in the gray/black areas, which you can do with PNG images. You can look through the sweater onto the animated background color, but there's still a bit of black on top which makes it darker.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That helped me understand the concept. Thanks again. Happy New Year in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

It is just an .gif image used as background-image.

Url to the image: http://static.tumblr.com/f13b0a6a22dd72346d930867ce349dff/zatppvx/DVQmt82k8/tumblr_static_colour-big.gif

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response. I'm a little confused. The logo Tt is a transparent  image but if you scroll down there's a Sweater image on the left side. It's got texture on it. If the image is transparent how does it retain its texture (and match background color) ?