# How to have a timed-gradient effect?

Tags: javascript, css

I want a circle border to have different color displayed every 2 seconds. I would prefer if it was a gradient, so the colors do not pop out.

**JavaScript**

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $(".circle").css("border", "10px solid blue")
}, 2000);
```

**CSS**

```
.circle{
    background-color: #000;
    border-radius: 500px;
    border: 10px solid #FFF;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:20px;
    height: 500px;
    line-height:100px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    text-align:center;
    width: 500px;
}
```

Comment: Do you want the colors to slowly shift between one another? Do you want a fixed set of X colors?

Comment: Meh, I dont mind any set of colors. All the colors of the palette is fine. Or it would be cool to have something like all shades of blue

Comment: My answer below is very basic. If you want constant color transitions, you should take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19639506/continuous-color-transition). Also, you are targeting the `border` with your CSS. Were you instead aiming to change the `background-color`?

Comment: Nope! I wanted to change the border color :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a CSS-only solution:

You can use CSS `animations` to change the border color over time.

**HTML**

```
<div></div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border-radius:1000px;
    border-width:10px;
    border-style:solid;
    -webkit-animation: changeColor 10s; 
    animation: changeColor 10s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
    animation-direction: alternate;
}

@-webkit-keyframes changeColor {
    0%   {border-color: red;}
    33%  {border-color: yellow;}
    66%  {border-color: blue;}
    100% {border-color: green;}
}

@keyframes changeColor {
    0%   {border-color: red;}
    33%  {border-color: yellow;}
    66%  {border-color: blue;}
    100% {border-color: green;}
}
```

And here's the [final product](http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/1aatfjph/).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to use a `setInterval`:

```
var i = setInterval(function () {
    var color = '#' + (Math.random()*0xFFFFFF|0).toString(16);
    // this produces a random hex code
    // taken from http://www.paulirish.com/2009/random-hex-color-code-snippets/
    $(".circle").css("border", "10px solid " + color);
}, 2000);
```

To color them each differently:

```
var i = setInterval(function () {
    $(".circle").each(function () {
        var color = '#' + (Math.random()*0xFFFFFF|0).toString(16);
        $(this).css("border", "10px solid " + color);
    })
}, 2000);
```

## [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Luxelin/Lzd1s2dL/1/)

Comment: Is it just me or the set interval works just once? :/

Comment: Like it works but just once. If no one is able to provide gradient, ill pick you as best answer :) Thanks bud

Comment: @Indigo By once, do you mean each circle is colored the same way? The interval definitely runs multiple times on my computer.

Comment: Yup I meant that! Ill look into the once issue might be overriding or something :P

Comment: Am I supposed to put the setInterval in some on load or init tag or something?

Comment: Your doodle, looks amazing :D

Comment: The `16777215` part can be made into `0xFFFFFF` for better readability: `"#"+(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF|0).toString(16)`

Answer (score 1):

What if something like this was done ... Start with a border and change the color randomly, but use a transition between colors on the border to allow for a smooth change.

CSS:

```
.circle {
    border: 10px solid blue;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var i = setInterval(function () {
    var color = '#' + ((Math.random()*16777215) | 0).toString(16);
    $(".circle").css({
        transition : 'border-color 2s ease-in-out',
        borderColor: color
    });
}, 2000);
```

Tested ... **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rfornal/ojegd9cg/)**